# What is the noun to use when describing the characteristic of another word being plural (or not)?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-number

In editing a document, I changed a word from a singular form to a plural one, and I want to leave a comment explaining what I did.  The comment I wanted to write went something like this: "changed the ??? of this word for consistency".

My first guesses were "plurality" or "multiplicity", but after reviewing the definitions of those, I'm don't think that's quite right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Funny how this question is tagged with the answer...

Comment: Probably not to OP.

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA "grammatical number"?  That's awful.

Comment: @BenCollins then call it 'number agreement' or 'plurality' or 'unicorns'.

Comment: [Whom you call awful?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number)

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA Haha! Saw that after I answered and edited the post!  Maybe you want to change it back so your comment makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the *[grammatical number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number)* of the noun:

> In linguistics, **grammatical number** is a [grammatical category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_category) of nouns, pronouns, and adjective and verb [agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29) that expresses count distinctions (such as "one", "two", or "three or more").<sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#cite_note-0)</sup>

But you can use *number agreement* if you're specifically comparing one word's grammatical number to another's.

Also, *[plurality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural)* is in fact an accepted word for this:

> In [linguistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics), **plurality** or **[a] plural** is a concept of [quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity) (i.e., [grammatical number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number)) representing a value of "*other-than-one*".

Take your choice.

Comment: I went with 'grammatical number'.  Thanks (and thanks to RegDwight AAA).

Comment: OED's first definition of *plurality* is *The state of being plural; the fact or condition of denoting, comprising, or consisting of more than one*, which isn't "linguistics-specific". Personally I think in a linguistics/grammar context (which is what we have here on ELU), *plurality* would normally be understood to mean *the attribute which can have either of the values **singular** or **plural***.